# Cannot get pointer to member funtion out of decltype

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, pointer-to-member

I've observed I cannot do `&decltype(c)::f` to get a pointer to member function `f` using a class instance `c`, but I can do `&C::f` to get that pointer to member function, using the class type `C`, which I believe is the same as `decltype(c)`.

See this minimal example:

```
struct C{
    int f()
    {
        return 5;
    }
} c;

template<typename T, T t, typename S, S*s> void callCf()
{
    (s->*t)();
}

int main()
{
  callCf<decltype(&decltype(c)::f),&decltype(c)::f,C,&c>();
}
```

Compiling this gives:

```
In function 'int main()':
15:3: error: parse error in template argument list
15:58: error: no matching function for call to 'callCf()'
15:58: note: candidate is:
8:49: note: template<class T, T t, class S, S* s> void callCf()
8:49: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
15:58: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

Using the following works as expected:

```
int main()
{
  callCf<decltype(&decltype(c)::f),&C::f,C,&c>();
}
```

Even this works:

```
int main()
{
  using tC = decltype(c);
  callCf<decltype(&decltype(c)::f),&tC::f,C,&c>();
}
```

This also works:

```
template<typename T>
struct forward_type{
    typedef T type;
};

int main()
{
  callCf<decltype(&decltype(c)::f),&forward_type<decltype(c)>::type::f,C,&c>();
}
```

My question is: why is it not possible to use decltype to obtain a pointer to member function like this `&decltype(c)::f`?

Edit: @Paul Sanders has shown in the comments that the minimal example works in `c++17`. I'm still using `c++14`. Does `c++17` include some changes to the language that allow my minimal example to compile?

Comment: What compiler and version are you using?  This [works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ncyTzzOgvQJWRDzz) for me.

Comment: I see it works on `c++17`. I'm using `c++14`, also gcc 6.1.0

Comment: Can you change your compiler flags to [C++17](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pv0EFLVGWJtkjhUJ)?  Not sure why that's necessary, I'm not a standards expert.

Comment: @PaulSanders Well, that is definitely a solution... Although it involves moving a lot of code to the new standard, which is not very convenient at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

`c` is an lvalue, so [`decltype(c)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) will not return the `C` type itself, which is why `decltype(c)::f` does not work.  `decltype(c)` will actually return a `C&` reference type instead:

> 2. If the argument is any other expression of type `T`, and
>    ...
>    b) if the value category of `expression` is *lvalue*, then decltype yields `T&`;
>    ...

You can use [`std::remove_reference/_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) to get the `C` type from `C&`, eg:

```cpp
int main()
{
    callCf<
        decltype(&std::remove_reference_t<decltype(c)>::f),
        &std::remove_reference_t<decltype(c)>::f,
        std::remove_reference_t<decltype(c)>,
        &c
    >();
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/rpviWu)

Which can then be simplified with a `using` statement:

```cpp
int main()
{
    using tC = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(c)>;
    callCf<decltype(&tC::f), &tC::f, tC, &c>();
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/vcqFa8)

Comment: Nice. Even `callCf<decltype(&C::f),&std::remove_reference<decltype(c)>::type::f,C,&c>();` works directly without `using`. My question is now why does `callCf<decltype(&decltype(c)::f),&decltype(c)::f,C,&c>();` work in `c++17`?

Comment: If you are fine with a `using` directive, then `using tC = decltype(c);` already works in `c++14`. I have no idea why it works though.

Comment: I've realized you do not need `std::remove_reference` you just need to forward the type through a different template such as `template<typename T>struct forward_type{ typedef T type; };`

Comment: If I define a function `C fun_ret_C(){return C();}` so that it returns an r-value C instance, `&decltype(fun_ret_C())::f` still gives error in `callCf<decltype(&C::f),&decltype(fun_ret_C())::f,C,&c>();`, so it seems to me the issue is not with rvalue or rvalue. Also the error is `parse error in template argument list`, which is suspicious...